# Is $(x^2+1)/(x^2+2)$ Bijective?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am unable to conclude if the function $F\colon \mathbf{R}\to \mathbf{R}$,
$F(x) = (x^2 + 1) / (x^2 + 2)$ bijective or not?

Also guide me if im wrong that does bijective mean ,
Injectivity holds & Surjectivity holds implies bijectivity holds.

Comment: Notice that $F$ is even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not injective because it's even

It's not surjective because its range goes from the minimum $[0.5,1)$  and therefore doesn't cover all $\mathbb{R}$

It was enough to say that it is not injective, anyway

Comment: I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Perhaps more simply, one only has to observe that both the numerator and denominator are always positive, so no negative number can be in the range of $f$, hence $f$ cannot be surjective (I'm not sure that this is *much* simpler than actually determining the range, but it saves one or two multiplications).  :\

Comment: @user236182 Thank you for correcting me

Comment: @XanderHenderson, that’s the way I look at it, and it seemed so obvious to me that I was surprised that OP didn’t notice it.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2+1}{x^2 + 2}\implies f'(x) =\frac{2x}{(x^2 + 2)^2} $$
and

$$f'(x) \le 0~~\text{for $x\le 0$}~~\text{and }~~~f'(x) \ge 0~~~\text{for $x\ge 0$}$$
the derivative change the sign then $f$ is not monotone and therefore not Bijective.